# How can i define a Loginmodule from Glassfish asadmin?

Tags: security, glassfish, realm, asadmin

I'm currently implementing a Glassfish realm backed by a neo4j DB, for which I've defined a `Realm` and a `LoginModule` class.

I can install the realm using the [`create-auth-realm asadmin`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/create-auth-realm-1.html#scrolltoc) command. But the realm is recognized by Glassfish only if it is associated to a `LoginModule` defined in the `config/login.conf` file.

For instance, in my case, I have to do the following:

1. Create the authentication realm: 
    `create-auth-realm --classname com.mycompany.security.MyRealm --property jaas-context=MyLoginModule myrealm` 
   and then
2. Define `MyLoginModule` in that `config/login.conf` file :

   ```
   MyLoginModule { 
     fr.mycompany.security.MyLoginModule required; 
   };
   ```

I can edit the `login.conf` file by hand but would like to use an asadmin command to automate this step. 
Would you know of such an asadmin command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that, at the moment, the Glassfish CLI does not support this.

Quote from [**here**](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/4757):

> glassfish has a pretty good CLI (which is actually one of the reasons,
>   why I switched over from JBoss). However, there is no CLI cmd for
>   modifying the login.conf of an instance (i.e. add/remove an entry in a
>   reliable way).
>
> I'm wondering about why the realm is not added/removed automatically
>   to/from the login.conf, when one creates/deletes a realm using the
>   create-auth-realm/delete-auth-realm command ...

I have [**requested**](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/4757) for an update.

Comment: @OlivierJ. The Glassfish CLI does not currently support this. Check out the links in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I don't have account on java.net so I can't see the link. I will just copy/paste so